# How to handle multiple jobs in a queue with fixed number of threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

In the below program I have posted 5 jobs to the queue, but have created only 3 threads. When I run the program, only 3 jobs are completed. How am I supposed to complete all 5 jobs with only 3 threads? Is there a way to the make a thread that has completed its job take the next job?

```
import time
import Queue
import threading

class worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,qu):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.que=qu

    def run(self):
        print "Going to sleep.."
        time.sleep(self.que.get())
        print "Slept .."
        self.que.task_done()


q = Queue.Queue()

for j in range(3):
    work = worker(q);
    work.setDaemon(True)
    work.start()


for i in range(5):
    q.put(1)


q.join()

print "done!!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your worker threads run in a loop. You can use a sentinel value (like `None` or custom class) to tell the workers to shut down after you've put all your actual worked items in the queue:

```
import time
import Queue
import threading

class worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,qu):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.que=qu

    def run(self):
        for item in iter(self.que.get, None): # This will call self.que.get() until None is returned, at which point the loop will break.
            print "Going to sleep.."
            time.sleep(item)
            print "Slept .."
            self.que.task_done()
        self.que.task_done()


q = Queue.Queue()

for j in range(3):
    work = worker(q);
    work.setDaemon(True)
    work.start()


for i in range(5):
    q.put(1)

for i in range(3):  # Shut down all the workers
    q.put(None)

q.join()

print "done!!"
```

Another option would be to use a [`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), which is a thread pool that Python manages for you:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def run(i):
    print "Going to sleep..."
    time.sleep(i)
    print "Slept .."

p = Pool(3)  # 3 threads in the pool

p.map(run, range(5)) # Calls run(i) for each element i in range(5)

p.close()
p.join()

print "done!!"
```